# Assigning data from firebase in useeffect only working once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am relatively new to react and to firebase (building my first "real"project at the moment).

The connection to firebase seems to work, cause I can log out the data in the console.
However, as soon as I try to really work with it it disappears, which it also does, after refreshing the page. I suppose it is some kind of newbie error.. could it have something to do with the function being called in useEffect? Thank you very much.

```
      const getMovieList = async () => {
    try{
      const data = await getDocs(moviesCollectionRef);
      
      //get data from firebase
      const filteredData = data.docs.map((doc)=>({...doc.data(),id:doc.id}))


      filteredData.map((movie)=>{
        
        setFirebaseData([...firebaseData,movie])
      })


    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=> {    
    
    getMovieList();
    console.log(firebaseData)


  },[])
```

Output is just an empty array.

For some reason it sometimes works. i.e. when I change something and save the code but do not refresh the page. After refreshing the array is empty again...

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `setFirebaseData` is part of `useState` declaration and `filteredData` is not empty so your issue is in seting state variable inside a map array. Refactoring your code it should look something like this:

```
const [firebaseData, setFirebaseData] = useState([])
  
// fetch data from firebase and assign to state variable
useEffect(()=> {    
  (async () => {
    try {
      const {docs} = await getDocs(moviesCollectionRef)
      setFirebaseData(() => docs.map(doc => ({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id
      })))
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  })()
},[])

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('firebase data', firebaseData)

  ....
}, [firebaseData])
```

OBS: When you refresh the page everything is reseted and you need to fetch data from database again or you can store it in localstorage but it's basically the same as fetching from database.

EDIT: If you want to keep data between page changes (not page REFRESH) you should create a react context. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-pine-76ln9t?file=/src/Test.tsx) is a little working example.

Comment: Thanks I just tested it, but it seems to deliver the same result. It works once and then delivers an empty array. Edit: yes you are right. setFirebaseData is part of useState and the filteredData has the data I am looking for. ```Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { tmdbid: 346698, id: "3uHSFodcPcxKsk5zxqTh" }
​
1: Object { tmdbid: 298618, id: "58d3Cn78V7qkp61VDqGL" }
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: Array []
App.js:27
```